# Compress swap pages written to disk

Tags: linux, swap, zswap

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192155/143394) says that zswap decompresses pages before writing them to non-RAM swap.

Is there any way to compress the pages written to disk, ideally with lz4?

I hope to:

- Reduce SSD write wear
- Reduce swap disk allocation
- Speed up swap IO (hopefully fewer blocks are written/read to/from disk)

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I've found is not using a dedicated swap partition and [storing the swapfile in a zfs partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347620/compressed-swapfile-without-zram-or-zswap).

Comment: [`From kernel 5.0+ btrfs have native swap files support, but with some limitations. Swap file - must be fully allocated as NOCOW with no compression on one device.`](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Does_btrfs_support_swap_files.3F)